# Durandal transition slow on android

Tags: javascript, android, performance, transition, durandal

I'm going to develop a hybrid App using Phonegap + Durandal.
So far I'm developing a classic Webapp and planing to do the switch to hybrid as soon as I'm satisfied with the feature set of the app.

I realized so far that the transitions Durandal is executing when switching from one view to another are pretty sloppy and non-fluid when using my Nexus 4 or Nexus 7 Tablet.

Does anyone have an idea how to speed it up? The final option will be to turn of transitions at all but that would be pretty sad =(

Update:
Ok found out that e.g. entrance.js seems to use Javascript Animations instead of CSS3 animations. guess thats where to start fixing

Comment: Just googling 'slow transitions android' the problem appears to be an Android specific problem and not one related to Durandal or it's transitions.  Some mention this specifically happens on Android devices as a setting that can be changed -

Go to: Settings > Developer options > Transition animation scale > Turn it off

Comment: Yep of course it's Android specific, but that doesn't mean it can't work at all. I guess there is some CSS issue there, I'm simply not that good with CSS3 transforms to figure it out.

Comment: Ok, but your question is titled 'Durandal transition slow on android' but should be more aptly titled 'Transitions slow on Android' or 'JavaScript transitions slow on Android'

Comment: Right because I wanted to know how to speed up transition effects from one view to another in Durandal for Android, not for Android in general. Means where in the Durandal API to search for the slow code and what to replace there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did use this library:
[css3 transit](https://github.com/rstacruz/jquery.transit) is much faster that default

and change the entrance.js (probably you need to adapt for you but this worked for me)

```
﻿define(['../system'], function(system) {
var fadeOutDuration = 100;

var entrance = function(parent, newChild, settings) {
    return system.defer(function(dfd) {
        function endTransition() {
            dfd.resolve();
        }

        function scrollIfNeeded() {
            if (!settings.keepScrollPosition) {
                $(document).scrollTop(0);
            }
        }

        if (!newChild) {
            scrollIfNeeded();

            if (settings.activeView) {
                $(settings.activeView).transition({
                      opacity: 1,
                      scale: 0.3,
                      duration: duration,
                      easing: 'in',
                      complete: function(){
                        $(settings.activeView).css('display' ,'none');
                            if (!settings.cacheViews) {
                                ko.virtualElements.emptyNode(parent);
                            }
                            endTransition();
                        }
                    });


            } else {
                if (!settings.cacheViews) {
                    ko.virtualElements.emptyNode(parent);
                }
                endTransition();
            }
        } else {
            var $previousView = $(settings.activeView);
            var duration = settings.duration || 500;

            function startTransition() {
                scrollIfNeeded();

                if (settings.cacheViews) {
                    if (settings.composingNewView) {
                        ko.virtualElements.prepend(parent, newChild);
                    }
                } else {
                    ko.virtualElements.emptyNode(parent);
                    ko.virtualElements.prepend(parent, newChild);
                }

                var startValues = {
                    //marginLeft: '90%',
                    //marginRight: '-20px',
                    opacity: 0,
                    scale: 0.3,
                    display: 'block'
                };

                var endValues = {
                    //marginRight: 0,
                    //marginLeft: 0,
                    opacity: 1,
                    scale: 1
                };
                $(newChild).page();
                $(newChild).trigger('create');
                $(newChild).css(startValues);
                $(newChild).transition(
                    {
                      marginRight: 0,
                      marginLeft: 0,
                      opacity: 1,
                      scale: 1,
                      duration: duration,
                      easing: 'in',
                      complete: endTransition
                    });
                    //startValues,500, 'ease');
                //$(newChild).transition(endValues, duration, 'swing', endTransition);
                //$(newChild).transition({ opacity: 0.1, scale: 0.3 }, 500, 'in', function() {..});
                //endTransition();
            }

            if ($previousView.length) {
                $previousView.transition({
                      opacity: 0,
                      scale: 0.3,
                      duration: 500,
                      easing: 'in',
                      complete: function(){
                          $previousView.css('display' ,'none');
                          startTransition();
                      }
                });

                //$('.news').css('display','none');

                //$previousView.fadeOut(fadeOutDuration, startTransition);
            } else {
                startTransition();
            }
        }
    }).promise();
};

return entrance;
```

});

sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Hi, sorry took me long to take a closer look. In the meantime I've used jquery transit as well and agree that made the effect smoother. Thanks for your example, helped to fix some stuff in my version